# Running a downloaded file

Tags: networking, software-installation

I currently have Ubuntu 17.04 and I just installed it so I have nothing on it right now, including internet connection.

I have a desktop with an Ethernet cable and I'm trying to connect to a school network.

To do so they require a program to be ran to configure the network access.

I have that downloaded and placed in my downloads folder (default location) how do I get to through the terminal and run this?

[image: this is the file I need to run - Cloudpath-x64]

I believe I have found the script to actually run it but currently I am having difficulty just getting to that directory.

But if you could also list the install command that would still be helpful.

And if you could link a website for total nooks that list commands and explanations that would also be beneficial.

Comment: http://hosted.cloudpath.net/CaseWesternReserveUniversity/Production/page4_download.html says you just have to run the `Cloudpath-x64` file. Open a terminal and execute `cd ~/Downloads/Cloudpath/ && chmod +x ./Cloudpath-x64 && sh ./Cloudpath-x64`. If it doesn't work, add the terminal output to your question in a code block (`{}` button).

Comment: "To do so they require a program to be ran to configure the network access. "     Ouuh, sounds ugly. ______ This sounds like a Windows config stuff. DO NOT DO IT until you exactly checked the content!! This may destroy a lot and not help at all. Set the network settings manually!! Ask for the details and set it right yourself. Probably they want a proxy to be installed. Look at a workung machine and copy the important stuff. WARNING: If they use a whitelist you will not connect as long as your machine is not registered with them (mostly the MAC address is used).   Good hook to learn Linux!!

Comment: Hi! Sorry I took so long to get back to this, I have been going through different avenues and it was getting very frustrating. Fortunately, I got the Internet to work, but I had to purchase a WiFi USB adapter. Then I installed ndiswrapper-1.61.tar.gz manually and that got me my connection. Unfortunately, I am still not able to use my Ethernet connection (I have a desktop). I installed WINE, but that wasn't able to open the network configure, is there another program that may be able to run this?

Answer (score 0):

I have used Ubuntu for a while but still learning. A quick guide to commands can be found at: [cheatography.com](https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/linux-command-line/)

Also I have just started reading " How Linux Works" by Brian Ward. Published by "No Starch Press" and available to buy on line. It is a fairly large book but explains, mostly in simple terms how Linux/Ubuntu work.
***One thing you must learn first is how to back up your system and files,*** especially before carrying out any task that may corrupt your system.

I use the backup utility that comes with Ubuntu and I also find a program called "Grsync" very useful. It synchronises two sets of files/folders or your complete home folder to a different location, and is available from the software centre.